# How to close iframe from within an iframe cross origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have created a page which will be used by the endusers through iframe.
Inside the page which i have created there are two buttons Submit and Decline. On click of the decline button i want to close the iframe. I have tried couple of methods but getting permission denied error due to cross origin as my webpage will be on the another server and the enduser who is going to consume my page through iframe will be on different server.

Methods which I tried is

Using ContentWindow,

window.parent

and also tried to get current page parent url and redirect at the same page
window.top.href = window.top

Comment: You can not get access across domain boundaries. Pretty much the only thing you can do, is use `postMessage` to send a message to the parent site. The parent then would have to listen for that message, and “close” the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution using an overlay (`<nab>`) `z-index`ed over the `<iframe>`, a button in the overlay (`<label for="dismiss">`), and a `[hidden]` checkbox associated with the `<label for="dismiss">` (`<input id='dismiss'>`). Once the `<label for='dismiss'>` is clicked by user, the `<input id='dismiss'>` gets `:checked` which causes the `<section>` containing the `<iframe>` to disappear.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

:checked+section {
  width: 0vw;
  height: 0vh;
  left: -999vw;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 7ch;
  height: 2ch;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2.5ch);
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 12;
  border: 2.5px outset grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font: 2.5ch/1 "Segoe UI";
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <input id='dismiss' type='checkbox' hidden>
  <section>
    <nav>
      <label for='dismiss'>Dismiss</label>
    </nav>
    <iframe src='https://example.com' scrolling='no'></iframe>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```